# Basic information about Quantum k-Means

Tags: quantum-algorithms, artificial-intelligence

I think I already understand the basics of the quantum k-means.
So first we should apply the amplitude encoding technique on our n input vector.
The amplitude encoding is coding the input vector in a quantum state. Then we could divide our quantum k-means into three different subcategories.

1. SwaptTest
2. DistCalc
3. Grovers optimize

Am I right ?